# Import and require used together

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, require

Recently I come into this:

```
import foo = require("/foo");
```

This sound me really weird, as I usually use require like this:

```
var foo = require("/foo");
```

Or import like this:

```
import foo from "/foo";
```

So, what's the point of that?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [the export = and import = require()](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) part of the docs:

> When importing a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import let
>   = require("module")` must be used to import the module

You can write it like this as well:

```
import foo = require("/foo");
```

Comment: This is interesting, I have come across an eslint error forcing me to use `import require` and this topic is already 4 years old. How come I have never had any issues with it so far?

Answer (score 0):

The statements `import {foo} = require("/foo");` and `var foo = require("/foo");` are not equivalent. Say `/foo` is a file with the following contents:

```
export default { bar: 'bar' };
export const foo = 'hello';
```

With the first statement your variable `foo` will be `'hello'`. The `{}` is an [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). In the other case you will receive the default exports, which means `foo` will be the object `{ bar: 'bar' }`.

MDN has some good explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: You are focusing on the destructuring, but I believe the OP wanted to know the difference between the three methods of importing.